# volatile vs final fields performance

Tags: java, concurrency, memory-model

What is preferable for performance? Assume no to little contention

1. mutable class with volatile fields and updating them one by one
2. immutable class with final fields, an update cycle avoids the
   multi-field update and instead re-creates the class once

Volatiles require memory barriers on every write, I suppose the same is true for final fields? Meaning a single memory barrier upon object construction?

*Update for clarification:*

I feel the question is valuable on its own and answerable generically, taking into account the java memory model and current gen hardware. If you must assume specifics:

- the object is of course accessed from multiple threads, otherwise this exercise would be pointless
- a single object is long-lived, as in multiple hours
- there are hundreds to thousands of those objects, with hundreds to thousands of update events per second

Comment: Attempting to write to a final field will get caught at compile time.

Comment: There simply isn’t enough information to answer this.  It depends on what you’re doing with those objects.  Immutable objects are often a good design, but if you’re making a lot of changes, creating hundreds of new immutable objects frequently may impair performance.  Volatile fields only matter if you’re modifying an object from different threads.

Comment: If you have done sufficient profiling to be worried about this, you have done sufficient profiling to have data with which to answer your question. This smells like doublepluspremature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

`final` is a hint to the compiler that the field value cannot change. Any write attempts are caught at compile time. Reading a `final` value does not use a memory barrier. You cannot write to a `final` variable, so a memory barrier is meaningless.

Using the hint, the compiler (or the JIT) may replace a memory reference to a final value with a constant. So in terms of performance, `final` does not introduce any additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If the garbage-collector flushes every thread's cache between the last time an old object is accessed and the space being made available for a new object, and if no cache line contains data from multiple objects, then it would on most platforms be naturally impossible for a newly-constructed object to get loaded into any thread's cache before a reference to that object is stored in a location which is accessible to that thread, *even in the absence of any read barriers* (beyond the aforementioned once-per-GC-cycle system-wide barrier).  Further, if a compiler can tell that writes occur to multiple fields of an object will occur without any intervening writes to any other object whose reference may have been exposed, it could omit write barriers for all but the last.

The only time using `final` fields would be more expensive than `volatile` would be if it necessitated the creation of more objects to handle changes which could have been done "in place" with `volatile` fields.  Since many factors can affect object-creation cost, the only reliable way to judge which approach is more efficient under a particular set of circumstances on a particular system would often benchmark both.